# Design Pattern to handle waterfall processing

Tags: c#, excel, oop, design-patterns

So, imagine spaghetti code. A task should go from 1 to 2 then to 3, etc. If a task breaks, abort the program. I can write this in a procedural manner, but would like to know if there is a design pattern for this.

I looked at Chain of Responsibility, but it does not fit. I already know which process should handle each task. Master/Worker does not fit either because it needs to be processed step by step.

Concrete problem at hand is - allow user to upload an Excel file, compare file to the database table structure, then update the database.

Steps would be:

1. Upload the file - verify that file is uploaded, if not, return.
2. Verify that file is an excel file, if not, return.
3. Read file into a datatable, if error, return.
4. Get datatabe from the database, if error, return.
5. Load each datatable into respective 2D arrays, if error, return.
6. Compare if each array has same number of columns, if error, return.
   etc etc etc...

Is there a way to use a design pattern for this? Thanks.

Comment: Who needs a design pattern?  Nothing sacred about them. Code your problem to meet your requirements.  It sounds like a chain of transformations where each one can throw an exception and break out.  Feels like an obvious lambda to me.

Comment: Nothing a simple `goto` won't fix.

Comment: To me, object-oriented languages such as Java and C# are not suited for data processing. Note: it is just a remark not an answer to your specific problem.

Comment: @NazarMerza There's nothing in this question to imply _big data_ as a reason to use a data-specific language or technology.  If it's not big data, pretty sure c# is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a design patten to address this kind of situations and it's quite well known: [Pipeline](https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/ParallelPatterns/PatternLanguage/AlgorithmStructure/Pipeline.htm) or as MSDN calls it [Pipes and Filters Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn568100.aspx). Note that it is NOT part of the famous [Gang of Four design patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) and it can even be an architecture pattern.

It is mostly used when performing a large processing of data through smaller independent stages (or filters):

> This pattern is used for algorithms in which data flows through a
> sequence of tasks or stages.
>
> **Use the PipelineProcessing pattern when**:
> The problem consists of
> performing a sequence of calculations, each of which can be broken
> down into distinct stages, on a sequence of inputs, such that for each
> input the calculations must be done in order, but it is possible to
> overlap computation of different stages for different inputs as
> indicated in the figures in the Motivation section.

MSDN:

> **Use this pattern when**:
>
> - The processing required by an application can easily be decomposed    into a set of discrete, independent steps.
> - The processing steps    performed by an application have different    scalability requirements.

[image]

[image]

By using this pattern you can perform your process through smaller independent (and therefore more manageable) steps, maybe parallelize some of them and thus reach better performance and even have different implementations of each step (filter) and customize them easily using things like failure strategy or validation for each step.

Answer (score 0):

Design Patterns are patterns that work well, but are not necessarily intuitively developed. This problem I think falls into intuitive development.

Here's how I would attack it...

In pseudocode

```
bool DoTheWork(file)
{
  if (!IsUploaded(file))
    return false;
  if (!IsExcel(file))
    return false;
  if (!WriteToDataTable(file))
     return false;
   .... etc
   return true;
}
```

There maybe some error catching at some point in the nested functions ie...

```
bool WriteToDataTable(file)
{
   try 
   {
     // Details to write to your database
   } 
   catch (e)
   {
     errorLogging(e);
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do it procedurally. I thought there were an OOP pattern to boot.